# If cell contain specific text then open a specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba

today I've ask if someone can help me , but I think I didn't put the correct situation .

I will describe now deeply so everybody can understand and help me please. please see first the picture.

[image: Main issue]

On each horizontal line , if the cell "E" contain word like *Design* the link in cell "J" will open the sheet specific for design .
if cell "E" contain random name ,then cell "J" should open another sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
     Dim myRange As Range
     Dim myCell As Range
     If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J4:J153")) Is Nothing Then
     If Target.Value <> "" Then
       employee = Target.Offset(0, -7).Value
           Set myRange = Range("E4:E150")
           For Each myCell In myRange
           If myCell Like "*Design*" Or _
               myCell Like "*Junior*" Or _
               myCell Like "*Fresh*" Or _
               myCell Like "*designer*" Then
        Sheets("Employee Review Design").Visible = True
        Sheets("Employee Review Design").unprotect "1234"
        Sheets("Employee Review Design").Range("C3").Value = employee
        Sheets("Employee Review Design").Activate
        Sheets("Employee Review Design").protect "1234"
      Else
        Sheets("Employee Review").Visible = True
        Sheets("Employee Review").unprotect "1234"
        Sheets("Employee Review").Range("C3").Value = employee
        Sheets("Employee Review").Activate
        Sheets("Employee Review").protect "1234"
    End If
    Next myCell
    End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D4:D153")) Is Nothing Then
    Set fnameRange = Range("$D$4:" & Range("D4").End(xlDown).Address)
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="fullnames", RefersTo:=fnameRange
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You still need to explain what your code is doing in error.  We should not have to guess the error to fix.  Please explain what your code does and where it errors.

Comment: If users select `J2` then open `Employee Review Design` sheet, if `J3` is selected then open `Employee Review` sheet. Is it your expected result?

Comment: sorry . I try to explain better . 
in the image attached as example.
"E4" contain   Design  then "J4" need to open sheet "Employee Design Review".
"E5" contain another name let say random . then  "J5" should open another sheet " Employee Review ".
now the issue is the code above not working . still open only one sheet .it's like there is no condition.
many thanks

Comment: @taller yes exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Updating the named range (`fullnames`) doesn't make any sense if users didn't change Col D.

Split it into two events Sub:

- `Worksheet_SelectionChange` : open the sheet when users select a cell on Col J
- `Worksheet_Change` : update named range reference of `fullnames` only when users change a cell on Col D

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myCell As String, sSht As String
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            If .Row > 3 And .Column = 10 And Len(.Value) > 0 Then
                myCell = Me.Cells(.Row, "E")
                If myCell Like "*Design*" Or myCell Like "*Junior*" Or myCell Like "*Fresh*" Or myCell Like "*designer*" Then
                    sSht = "Employee Review Design"
                Else
                    sSht = "Employee Review"
                End If
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                With Sheets(sSht)
                    .Visible = True
                    .Unprotect "1234"
                    .Range("C3").Value = Me.Cells(Target.Row, "C").Value
                    .Activate
                    .Protect "1234"
                End With
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim oName As Name, fnameRange As Range
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            If .Row > 3 And .Column = 4 Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Set oName = ThisWorkbook.Names("fullnames")
                On Error GoTo 0
                Set fnameRange = Me.Range("D4", Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
                If oName Is Nothing Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="fullnames", RefersTo:=fnameRange
                Else
                    If Mid(Replace(oName.RefersTo, Chr(34), ""), 2) <> _
                        Split(fnameRange.Address(True, True, , True), "]")(1) Then
                        oName.Delete
                        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="fullnames", RefersTo:=fnameRange
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: you're the best . I don't know how to thank you more than words . 
many many thanks it works perfectly .

Comment: I've updated `Worksheet_Change` to make it more reliable.

Comment: many many thanks . I'm still learning  VBA so I will never make it as you did .
thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Your code might be working at searching 'Employee' in the correct sheet. What might be happening is that after finding 'Employee' value, the next 'For' it's iterating all values in column 'Job Position'. Overall I guess you want to select a single 'Employee' and to read it's 'Job Position' for that single employee. Since iteration goes from 'Range(E4:E150)' the loop ends at E150 which might be having and Empty value for 'Job Position', explaining why only sheet "Employee Review" is being loaded, and a conditioned value is needed to be diferent than Empty to "Employee Review Design" being displayed.

Adjust like this:

```
'Usage: Detect selection event to open Employee's Review
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim rng_Employee As Range, ix_Employee as Long
  Dim myCell As Range
      

    'Check event in column
    Set rng_Review = Target.Parent.Range("J4:J153")
    VALID_INTERSECT = (Not Intersect(Target, rng_Review) Is Nothing)
    VALID_VALUE = (Target.Value <> "")
    VALID_CONDITIONS = (VALID_INTERSECT And VALID_VALUE)


    'Start script
    If VALID_CONDITIONS Then

        'Get data from table
        Set rng_Employee = Target.Offset(0, -7)       'ListColumn (C): "Employee"
        Set rng_JobPosition = Target.Offset(0, -5)    'ListColumn (E): "Job Position"

        'Get employee index        
        ix_Employee = rng_Employee.Value              
       
        'Check Job Position
        With rng_JobPosition
            If .Value Like "*Design*" Or _
               .Value Like "*Junior*" Or _
               .Value Like "*Fresh*" Or _
               .Value Like "*designer*" Then
            
                'Set sheet name (Option 1)
                ReviewSheetName = "Employee Review Design"

            Else
                'Set sheet name (Option 2)
                ReviewSheetName = "Employee Review"
            End If

        End With   '->  This_JobPosition


        'Open requested Review
        Call OpenReview(ReviewSheetName, Employee)
    

    End If

    '[This part I am clueless of what it does]
'    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D4:D153")) Is Nothing Then
'        Set fnameRange = Range("$D$4:" & Range("D4").End(xlDown).Address)
'        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="fullnames", RefersTo:=fnameRange
'    End If


End Sub



'Usage: Open Review sheet by name and set Employee on it
Function OpenReview(ReviewSheetName as String, EmployeeIndex as String)
  Dim shtReviewSheet as Worksheet

    'Select Review Sheet
    Set shtReviewSheet = Sheets(ReviewSheetName)
    
    'Change sheet settings
    With shtReviewSheet
        .Visible = True
        .unprotect "1234"
        .Range("C3").Value = EmployeeName 
        .Activate
        .protect "1234"
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: many thanks . as you explained , its exactly how it works.
thanks also to taller . the code he write is working perfect for me .
I tested yours also , it works also very well . 
many thanks